# How can a UA Mystic increase their Discipline attack bonus or save DC?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, unearthed-arcana, mystic

I am creating a wish-list of what kind of magic items I could get for a [Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf) in D&D 5e. I am hoping to empower their mystic disciplines, but most if not all magic items made for casters explicitly say *"spell attack bonus"* or *"spell save DC"*, which do not apply to the Mystic's *"Discipline attack bonus"* and *"Discipline save DC"*.

The only item I could find was the Ioun Stone of Mastery which increases my Proficiency Bonus.

Are there any other magic items in 5e, official books or UA, that can empower a Mystic's disciplines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The only official methods involve increasing your proficiency bonus or your Intelligence score.

You have already observed that the Ioun Stone of Mastery increases your proficiency bonus, which in turn increase your Discipline Save DC. The only other official method will be to increase your Intelligence score by one of the various methods. The most reliable method is to increase your Intelligence to 20 via Ability Score Improvements, or if your Intelligence is below 18, a Headband of Intellect will raise it to 19 for a +4 Int modifier. There is also an Ioun Stone specifically for Intelligence adding +2 to a maximum of 20. Additionally, the Tome of Clear Thought can increase your Intelligence beyond 20, adding +2 each time it is studied.

Consider asking your DM to adapt the Dragonhide Belt to the Mystic class. The Dragonhide Belt was added in *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons* specifically to give monks an item that increases their Ki save DC:

> This finely detailed belt is made of dragonhide. While wearing it, you gain a bonus to the saving throw DCs of your ki features. The bonus is determined by the belt’s rarity.

Comment: It's a shame that there isn't a series of Headbands like there are with Belts of Giant Strength. But I suppose it would be too strong for Wizards who also have access to Robes of the Archmagi or Arcane Grimoires.

Comment: @Toddleson actually the shame is that stat boost items exist at all, they absolutely break half the game